# lichess.org time out

Tags: visual

This may not be a puzzle in the manner that is used to be in the site, if so gently close it :)

I am playing in `www.lichess.org`, which is an online chess playing site.

Today I see a timeout screen for 30 seconds.

Here it is:

[image: lichess.org time out]

The screen is amazing , a girl playing chess with a robot while tickling his leg, there are some texts around `friend and family` `p-24` `p31t` ....

Do you think there is some sort of hidden message, concept or story in this picture or it is just a picture?!

Comment: I think this is just an image.

Comment: Also, it's more likely you get an answer by asking on their forum: https://en.lichess.org/forum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be a puzzle.

Comment: (Although I think a puzzle could probably be made from this)

Comment: This is an art by some user Gia. Here's the [original link](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=576091)

Comment: And there is a [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/11eqef/saw_this_awesome_drawing_while_lichessorg_was_down/) about it on reddit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking the simple approach to this image, all though I believe there are more than one way at looking at this image.

This image appears as a timeout screen for lichess.org.

So the robot could symbolise the lichess, the computer chess AI, a machine obsessed with chess. Accompanying the robot, there is a piece of text stating "PLAY CHESS". On the other hand, the girl may symbolise the player, a human with needs of comfort. Next to her, there is a piece of text saying, "Take a Rest". Along with that, there are other phrases and words, again all relating with comfort and relaxation and belonging.

Now we've got two opposite sides, one that lies inside the game of chess, the other a simple human. This might send a message trying to tell the user that they need to take a break and be with family and friends. Otherwise they might turn into the robot that spends all their time on chess, thinking, thinking, thinking all day long.

#### Symbols

- The girl: the user wanting to play chess
- The girl's robot chair: the interface used to access chess, this case the chair is the computer or the web
- The flower covered in darkness: the flower symbolises the world outdoors, it being in darkness means that the user (the girl) disregards outside activity

#### Edit 1:

I realised that this question is going to be closed as off-topic, but since I'm already finished with this description, I guess I'll post it anyways.